# Using Windows EXE file format in operating system

Tags: copyright, software, licensing

I know that adding Windows .exe file format can be very very hard. I want my OS to run .exe files and I'd like to know if I can use them freely in my OS without any risk or if I have to contact Microsoft for license.

Comment: Do you want your operating system to just be able to run EXE files, or do you want to actually copy some of the EXE files from Windows into your operating system?

Comment: I want my OS to just run EXE files

Comment: There is a huge difference between being able to run exe files and running exe files. I am able to steal, but I don't steal. One is legal and one is not.

Comment: What happens when the .exe file makes a library call to a Windows library?  Or will all your OS's .exe files be *designed specifically for* your OS, and naturally make only library calls to your OS's libraries?  Do you understand what I am saying?  To go into more depth, if a written-for-Windows .exe file makes a library call into your OS, will there be a library that works the same as Windows? And have you seen the first 4 episodes of *Halt and Catch Fire*? You should.

Comment: @IKnowNothing what law is violated by creating a system that runs exe files?

Comment: I want only use that how exe files work and I would make for that my own library and (maybe) my own compiler (but working similarly to Windows compilers). I want to know if exe format itself is copyrighted or something

Comment: @phoog that would all depend on who owns them. If you make your own exe files there are no problems. If you run Microsoft's exe files, they are probably protected by copyright laws.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica There are open-source recreations of the standard Windows libraries - check out Wine and ReactOS. If the asker only wants to run specific small programs, s/he could also implement them him/herself.

Comment: @phoog It''s not the creating as much as it is the running, if the copyright owner of the exe file did not license it for that use.

Comment: @IKnowNothing okay, but suppose I have an exe file that has been licensed to me to run as I see fit, or even one that I created myself, and I run it on dawidsk12345's system.  Nobody is stealing anything in that case.

Comment: @phoog Right, as long as this is someing dawidsk12345 consent to then that would be perfectly legal. It would also be perfectly legal to create a runtime that can execute such a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would essentially be creating a virtual machine that emulates the x86 achitecture (64-bit, 32-bit, 16-bit as many as you want/need), and possibly implementing your own .net runtime as well. This is perfectly legal to do and has been done (see examples WINE and MONO for linux).

Where you may run into legal issues is when executing EXE files that are owned by someone else. You would have to read the software license agreement and user6726's answer covers this in the Microsoft case. It is highly unlikely that Microsoft comes after you for doing this on your own machine, including friends and family. Lawyers simply cost too much.

Where you will definitely run into legal problems is if you start selling/distribute Microsoft's EXEs with your OS to the public. The more successful you become, the more certain it is that it is worth their while to sue you. If you want to do this you should definitely obtain permission from Microsoft, as well as any other third party software owners, whose files you wish to include with your OS.

Answer (score -1):

The legal answer depends on how you plan to actually do so. You can buy a license for W10 and install it on a computer. You might have another partition with a different OS which you have booted up, it sees the W10 partition, locates "explorer.exe", and attempts to execute that file. The license is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm): is this scheme consistent with the terms of the license, where you have a license for the software, and you didn't copy the software? The restrictions in (2)(c) say that

> The device manufacturer or installer and Microsoft reserve all rights
>   (such as rights under intellectual property laws) not expressly
>   granted in this agreement. For example, this license does not give you
>   any right to, and you may not:
>
> (i)      use or virtualize features of the software separately;

They do not go into any detail as to what it means to "use or virtualize features of the software separately", but I cannot see any plausible interpretation that does not render that use illegal. Ultimately, it depends on how you would do such a thing.

Comment: This answers a completely different question.